# How many accounts can a geth node hold/have? Any upper bound limits

Tags: go-ethereum

How many accounts can a geth node hold/have? Are there any upper bound limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fixed limit.

Many exchanges or other crypto companies run nodes with hundreds of thousands of accounts. [One particular commentator](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16940#issuecomment-396306029) on Github mentioned 200k+ accounts on one node, which prompted [an improvement](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/16958) in account iteration.

You should be able to have a fairly large amount without issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on the number of accounts that u can create from one node!! Its up to your device specifications whether it can handle that much or not!

Answer (score -1):

The number of accounts is limited by hardware only. There is no limit in software. So far there were 40 millions accounts created to date, not all of them currently stay active, though.

Comment: Was asking the limits on the node not the overall accounts created

Comment: @NathanAw the accounts are copied on every node. your node will have the same number of accounts as the state database contains